# how to: Setting up ROS on RaspberryPi

Tags: ros, installation, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

```
This is just a small how to re: getting ROS to work on the Raspberry Pi.
```

1. Pi Setup

I'm not going to go into a load of details here - but for me the main thing was to boot the Pi with as much memory as possible. With that in mind set the arm224_start.elf to be your start.elf file.

Also ensure you have a reasonable amount of swap space available (The build of ROS is on the Pi itself - I don't have a x-compiler to hand)

2. Building ROS

This is largely following the [Debian Instruction here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian) With a few notable exceptions:

- Update the turtlesim.cpp file to the attached one - else compilation problems (static_cast<> issue around std::max())
- Use just make and not "make -j8" - it's a single core machine and all 8 cpp threads will do it hang everything on waiting on IO - trust me I tried - 8 hrs later and still nothing... This step takes somewhere between 1-2 hrs. Not quite sure I left it to it.
- Before Section 1.5 (Build Higher Level Tools) type `export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=debian:squeeze` is it mentioned later in the install. I found you need it sooner.

Then Finish off up to 1.5's "rosdep install -a". At this time having problems getting past this. However this are the higher level fucntions that might be too much for the Pi.

Once that's done you should be able to run ROS. I've attached a small screen shot of rxconsole; turtlesim etc with a move command being published (from the tutorials).

A word of expectation it's slow. I expect the graphics drivers will have much to do with it (which are due to be changed to take advantage of the GPU).

[image: Screen Shot of ROS on Raspberry Pi]

But what the heck it's cool (tm) :)

Hope this is of some use/help

Mark

PS - If there is some where this how to would be better suited let me know/feel free to move it there.

[turtle.cpp](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13380029256697773.bmp) change the extension to cpp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34501/how-to:-setting-up-ros-on-raspberrypi/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-21

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on 2012-05-30**:
Great job! Will definitely try as soon as my Pi arrives. Even when it is slow, do you think it is usable when you distribute ROS-nodes over several Raspberry Pis?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-30**:
Yep that's what I'm hoping. As yet (As you'll see below 1.5 is proving troublesome) but I think the lower level stuff - distros will work well. Currently I'm slightly side tracked hoping to install rosjava on it too

**Comment by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on 2012-05-31**:
ok, I was expecting that. I hope that it is possible to run a full ROS installation on a strong master but have several Pi slaves with only low level functionality that take care of certain tasks only (like a Pi that does only arm navigation in a more complex robot that runs a quadcore master or so)

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-31**:
TilScout: Stick with Electric for now. I had ZERO luck getting Fuerte installed, but Electric went smoothly. Also, consider running Raspbian as the OS and doing the 800Mhz OC. That plus running OS off external drive makes things run a LOT smoother. You should be able to do what you're wanting to.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-31**:
@TillScout - yep I think that's a sound plan @mkopack lower level stuff should be working okay - good to hear Electric is a stable install! - rviz working? :)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-31**:
@TilScout - yep I think that's a sound plan

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-31**:
didn't try Rviz. As you said, everything is rather SLOOOOOOOW. I need to hook up an external USB drive and set up using that as that seems to make the whole Rpi run a LOT faster. on the Plus side, RPi #3 arrived today :) so I should be able to set all 3 up and make them a nice little ROS cluster.

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-31**:
Oh, and no dice on using Raspbian with Electric. Electric insists on having libboost1.42-dev-all and that doesn't exist for Raspbian. installing 1.49 (which Raspbian has) wouldn't get me past the error so I gave up for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Self answered ...

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-05-21**:
Please, please, please put this on the wiki.  That would definitely be the place to put it.  Maybe something like http://ros.org/wiki/ROSpberry_pi would be a good place?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-21**:
Perhaps ROSberryPi would be better :)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-21**:
Up will do this eve - liking the names :)

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-25**:
Can you upload the actual error message? Sounds like std libs are not getting included for some reason.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-31**:
I've finally set up a Wiki page - hope it's okay @mkopack I added your comments re: Raspbian. Please feel free to edit as needed. It can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Updating this to include some solutions to get things farther:

The issue here is that I'm running Raspbian for the OS and they had /tmp set up to be in RAM. I had to do the following to fix it:

1. in .bashrc, add:  export TMPFS=/var/tmp
2. then edit /etc/default/rcS and comment out the line that reads: RAMPTMP=yes
3. Reboot.

Additionally, it appears there was some sort of error in the install scripts that placed ROS in /opt/ros/fuert  not in /opt/ros/fuerte.

I had to do a: sudo mv /opt/ros/fuert /opt/ros/fuerte
to rename it, after performing step 1.3.2, and then repeat 1.3.2 to get it to put everything in the right place.

When I got to the "rosdep install -a" step though, I ran into the problems found here: http://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install-a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/

Unfortunately, I'm stuck again and I need to switch over to doing grad school work today. I'll try to get back to this tomorrow.

---

Originally posted by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) with karma: 171 on 2012-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-26**:
Looking at the first error...no space left on device...have you maxed out your SD card? The distro  is only 2GB

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-26**:
Also, I'm getting this output when the setup.bash runs:
rospack could not be found, you cannot have rosbash features until you bootstrap ros

Not sure if that's part of my problem, nor why I'm getting that.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-29**:
I've not got past rosdep install -a again due to http://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install-a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/ - this doesn't seem to work for me. To be honest I'm not sure how well the pi will get on with these processes.

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-30**:
ok, so you're having the same problem then? I was going to ask how the heck it worked for you but not me!

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-30**:
Ok, I'm going to give the instructions for Electric a try. It's a bit older and might have better Debian support.

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-05-30**:
Ok, electric install completed. I'm going to try to run through the tutorials in a bit... Will report once I give it a try.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-05-30**:
Yep same place as you - (I've edited the original to clarify) at the moment you should be able to set turtle sim etc working?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-03-10**:
@mkopack I am trying to get ROS Electric on to Raspberry Pi, if you were successful in your efforts then can you kindly put up an image ? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is just a clearer answer to the Wiki page (As mentioned in the comments)

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi

(Credit to @mkopack for the Raspbian info)

M

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-09-23**:
have you tried to get any USB cameras to capture video and publish it with image_transport?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-09-23**:
Yes and it works. Tried is the other day for, rviz on my main PC with usb_cam, custom robot publisher node, and roscore et al all on the pi. Was running about 60% CPU